# Can't remove directory that I'm owner of

Tags: permissions

I'm attempting to remove a directory I have permissions to, but for some reason I'm getting a permission denied error when attempting to remove it:

```
mage@vagrant:/var/www$ ls -la
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Oct 30 22:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Oct 30 22:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Oct 30 22:20 html
drwxrwxrwx  2 mage mage 4096 Oct 30 22:49 mage
mage@vagrant:/var/www$ whoami
mage
mage@vagrant:/var/www$ rm -R mage
rm: cannot remove 'mage': Permission denied
```

Any idea what could be causing this to happen?

Comment: I do have permissions. The owner and group is set to `mage` which is the same user I'm logged in as.

Comment: I'm not owner of `/var` or `/var/www` but I am owner of `/var/www/mage`, I thought as I'm the owner of the `mage` directory I should be able to delete it?

Comment: @BugHunterUK To delete `/var/www/mage` you have to alter  `/var/www` to remove `mage` from its contents. So you need write rights to   `/var/www` (the same would be true if you were creating or renaming `/var/www/mage`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is you're not the owner nor part of the group of the parent folder and that is what's blocking you. Run the same command with `sudo` in front of it without modifying the permissions or ownership of the `/var/www/` folder.

```
sudo rm -R mage/
```

Folders inherit the permissions from their parent folders. When you are the owner of the `mage/` folder, that will allow you to create new folders and files and delete them within the `mage/` folder. But, since the `mage/` folder is a subfolder of the `/var/www/` folder, which you do not have write or execute permissions to, you cannot create files or folders without `sudo` permission or changing the ownership or permissions of `/var/www/`. If `/var/www/` had permissions of `drwxrwxrwx` that would allow you as a user to delete that folder, **but this is not recommended as it could break your apache2 server.**

Your folder inherited the same permissions as its parent folder that is why you cannot delete the folder as a regular user.

Hope this helps!

Comment: To create new files in a folder you don't have to have write permissions on its superfolders, just execute permission is enough. See https://superuser.com/q/163070/1360183

Comment: @user14967413 Did you read that link?  That person will only be able to eXecute files. Not read or write into that folder.  "He will not be able to see or modify the contents, just traverse it."  Modifying requires the same permissions as write.

Comment: This is the intention for superfolders like `/var/www` - you set only execute rights on it so user will only be able to traverse it, not modify the contents. For the last subfolder like `/var/www/mage/` you set read/write permissions so user can list/create files there.

Comment: @user14967413 Yes, that is true, but the question here was about removing the directory that the OP was the owner of, not create new files within in.

Comment: You are right. Probably I have misunderstood your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue

It turned out I had a process currently using the directory I was trying to remove (namely: Visual Studio Code)

When I shut down Visual Studio Code, I was able to delete the directory without any issue